# How to skip the display of line number for commented lines?

Tags: vim

How to skip the display of line number for commented lines? I want to skip line number for every line that starts with `#` when coding python

here is what I mean:

```
1 print "hello"

  # skiping line number for commented line

2 print "line number for next line"

3 print "now the next line number"

  # again skipping another line that's commented with hash symbol

4 print "I hope you got what I meant!"
```

Comment: 1. It would make no sense. 2. You can't.

Comment: With wrapping you can do it but it will still virtual

Comment: I'm not sure what would make you want this, but I feel the need to point out that it would make things much more confusing for you. For instance, all of the referenced line numbers in stack traces would differ from Vim's displayed line numbers.

Comment: you could fold away the comments with the empty lines around it...

Answer (score 2):

> How to skip the display of line number for commented lines?

- The current vim version (v8.0) doesn't have built-in support for your requirement.
- It is hard (impossible perhaps) to implement as well even if you write a vim plugin.
- The answer is, do patch on vim source codes. If it is really important for you. I thought this would be a big effort, since you have to care about all line-based motions as well, and it will break many vim-plugins.
- Or use other text processing tool (awk?) to handle your text  automatically. But we have to know your final goal.

Answer (score -1):

I advocate use the hybrid numbering configuration and foregoing any idea of skipping lines since you'll be giving up some of the valuable motions that depend on comments being counted as lines. First, to turn on the hybrid line numbering in vim7.4+, add to your .vimrc:

```
set relativenumber 
set number
```

This gives you the absolute line numbers AND their relative line numbers from your current cursor line position. Next, work with not against vim's very sensible approach to reap its powerful ability to move lines using absolute line numbers, e.g:

```
:12m204
```

Which instructs vim to move line #204 right after line #12. Or with relative numbering:

```
:+12m.
```

Which tells vim to move the line 12 relative lines ahead to right after your current line. (The fancier variant is using marks and searches to move lines, e.g.: `:/foo/m'a`)

These kinds of motion control are handy when you want toggle comments -- the very thing you wanted to skip -- since you can do something like the following:

```
CtrlV 10j I#Esc
```

Which turns on visual block, moves the block 10 lines down and Inserts a hash comment. Obviously the reverse can be done as well, affording you an fast way to toggle chunks of code as a comment, which seems almost like a necessary capability while troubleshooting and not so easy to do if commented lines were skipped.